Heating a piece of metal using a circuit - calculating the time
If I have a circuit sitting on the surface on the top of a rectangular slab of metal, and I want to heat the metal using resistance heating in the circuit, how can I calculate how much in watts the circuit would need to produce in order to heat the metal in a period of one second? I have found a formula that says
$$Qt=cm(T_f−T_i)$$
where $c$ is the specific heat capacity, $m$ is the mass,
$T_f$ is the final temperature and $T_i$ is the initial temperature.
Can I use this if the circuit sits on top of the metal being heated? Will part of the circuit's heat dissipate and be lost? I guess the insulation of the circuit too will thermally insulate the circuit to some degree as well. Allowing for these two things, if I want to heat the metal in one second, how can I factor in the time in this situation?

please use MathJax to make your mathematical expressions readable.

As a crude approximation, if your circuit is just a resistor of resistance $R$ connected to a battery of voltage $V$, you could assume the energy dissipated in Joule heating (in a time $\Delta t$) is transferred to the metal. Then $(V^2/R)\Delta t=mc\Delta T$, where $\Delta T$ is the desired change in temperature.

Do you think the metal’stemperature will be uniform when the circuit is heating it?


Will part of the circuit's heat dissipate and be lost?

Yes. While the resistor is transferring energy to the metal slab, the slab will be transferring energy by means of heat to its surroundings by conduction, convection and radiation, the amounts depending on the characteristics of the surroundings.
Bottom line: the time it takes for the slab to reach the desired temperature $T_f$ in your equation would be the minimum time if there were no losses to the environment.
Hope this helps.
